How to solve Wordpress Webiste erros; Response is not a valid json response/ WP_Theme_JSON_Resolver::get_user_data()?
I am facing multiple errors on my wordpress website. I am not able to solve them, I have tried multiple solutions from across the web, but none have worked. Whenever I try to upload an image, I get the error that:
 The response is not a valid json reponse;

Also I face difficulty in updating present pages on my website and I also face issues in adding new plugins and themes. SSL plugin also gives error that:
Status code: 500, Server response: <script></script>{"fields":[{"default":false,"id":"ssl_enabled","visible":true,"disabled":false,"rec...

I tried debugging in wp-config file and get the foloowing erros on dashboard:

Notice: Function wp_enqueue_style was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or login_enqueue_scripts hooks. This notice was triggered by the low_diagnostic_glance_styles handle. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.3.0.) in /home/s3uoygwak2m1/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 6085
Notice: Function is_feed was called incorrectly. Conditional query tags do not work before the query is run. Before then, they always return false. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.1.0.) in /home/s3uoygwak2m1/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 6085
Notice: Function wp_enqueue_script was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or login_enqueue_scripts hooks. This notice was triggered by the low_diagnostic_glance_custom_admin_script handle. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.3.0.) in /home/s3uoygwak2m1/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 6085
Notice: WP_Theme_JSON_Resolver::get_user_data(): Error when decoding a theme.json schema for user data. Syntax error in /home/s3uoygwak2m1/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 6085
Notice: WP_Theme_JSON_Resolver::get_user_data(): Error when decoding a theme.json schema for user data. Syntax error in /home/s3uoygwak2m1/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 6085
Notice: WP_Theme_JSON_Resolver::get_user_data(): Error when decoding a theme.json schema for user data. Syntax error in /home/s3uoygwak2m1/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 6085

Functions.php of theme:
<?php
/**
 * Astra functions and definitions
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/theme-functions/
 *
 * @package Astra
 * @since 1.0.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

/**
 * Define Constants
 */
define( 'ASTRA_THEME_VERSION', '4.7.3' );
define( 'ASTRA_THEME_SETTINGS', 'astra-settings' );
define( 'ASTRA_THEME_DIR', trailingslashit( get_template_directory() ) );
define( 'ASTRA_THEME_URI', trailingslashit( esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ) ) );

/**
 * Minimum Version requirement of the Astra Pro addon.
 * This constant will be used to display the notice asking user to update the Astra addon to the version defined below.
 */
define( 'ASTRA_EXT_MIN_VER', '4.7.0' );

/**
 * Setup helper functions of Astra.
 */
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/core/class-astra-theme-options.php';
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/core/class-theme-strings.php';
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/core/common-functions.php';
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/core/class-astra-icons.php';

define( 'ASTRA_PRO_UPGRADE_URL', astra_get_pro_url( 'https://wpastra.com/pro/', 'dashboard', 'free-theme', 'upgrade-now' ) );
define( 'ASTRA_PRO_CUSTOMIZER_UPGRADE_URL', astra_get_pro_url( 'https://wpastra.com/pro/', 'customizer', 'free-theme', 'upgrade' ) );

/**
 * Update theme
 */
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/theme-update/astra-update-functions.php';
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/theme-update/class-astra-theme-background-updater.php';

/**
 * Fonts Files
 */
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/customizer/class-astra-font-families.php';
if ( is_admin() ) {
    require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/customizer/class-astra-fonts-data.php';
}

require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/lib/webfont/class-astra-webfont-loader.php';
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/lib/docs/class-astra-docs-loader.php';
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/customizer/class-astra-fonts.php';

require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/dynamic-css/custom-menu-old-header.php';
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/dynamic-css/container-layouts.php';
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/dynamic-css/astra-icons.php';
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/core/class-astra-walker-page.php';
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/core/class-astra-enqueue-scripts.php';
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/core/class-gutenberg-editor-css.php';
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/core/class-astra-wp-editor-css.php';
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/dynamic-css/block-editor-compatibility.php';
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/dynamic-css/inline-on-mobile.php';
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/dynamic-css/content-background.php';
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/class-astra-dynamic-css.php';
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/class-astra-global-palette.php';

/**
 * Custom template tags for this theme.
 */
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/core/class-astra-attr.php';
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/template-tags.php';

require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/widgets.php';
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/core/theme-hooks.php';
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/admin-functions.php';
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/core/sidebar-manager.php';

/**
 * Markup Functions
 */
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/markup-extras.php';
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/extras.php';
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/blog/blog-config.php';
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/blog/blog.php';
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/blog/single-blog.php';

/**
 * Markup Files
 */
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/template-parts.php';
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/class-astra-loop.php';
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/class-astra-mobile-header.php';

/**
 * Functions and definitions.
 */
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/class-astra-after-setup-theme.php';

// Required files.
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/core/class-astra-admin-helper.php';

require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/schema/class-astra-schema.php';

/* Setup API */
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'admin/includes/class-astra-api-init.php';

if ( is_admin() ) {
    /**
     * Admin Menu Settings
     */
    require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/core/class-astra-admin-settings.php';
    require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'admin/class-astra-admin-loader.php';
    require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/lib/astra-notices/class-astra-notices.php';
}

/**
 * Metabox additions.
 */
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/metabox/class-astra-meta-boxes.php';

require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/metabox/class-astra-meta-box-operations.php';

/**
 * Customizer additions.
 */
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/customizer/class-astra-customizer.php';

/**
 * Astra Modules.
 */
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/modules/posts-structures/class-astra-post-structures.php';
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/modules/related-posts/class-astra-related-posts.php';

/**
 * Compatibility
 */
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/compatibility/class-astra-gutenberg.php';
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/compatibility/class-astra-jetpack.php';
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/compatibility/woocommerce/class-astra-woocommerce.php';
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/compatibility/edd/class-astra-edd.php';
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/compatibility/lifterlms/class-astra-lifterlms.php';
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/compatibility/learndash/class-astra-learndash.php';
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/compatibility/class-astra-beaver-builder.php';
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/compatibility/class-astra-bb-ultimate-addon.php';
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/compatibility/class-astra-contact-form-7.php';
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/compatibility/class-astra-visual-composer.php';
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/compatibility/class-astra-site-origin.php';
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/compatibility/class-astra-gravity-forms.php';
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/compatibility/class-astra-bne-flyout.php';
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/compatibility/class-astra-ubermeu.php';
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/compatibility/class-astra-divi-builder.php';
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/compatibility/class-astra-amp.php';
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/compatibility/class-astra-yoast-seo.php';
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/compatibility/surecart/class-astra-surecart.php';
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/compatibility/class-astra-starter-content.php';
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/addons/transparent-header/class-astra-ext-transparent-header.php';
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/addons/breadcrumbs/class-astra-breadcrumbs.php';
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/addons/scroll-to-top/class-astra-scroll-to-top.php';
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/addons/heading-colors/class-astra-heading-colors.php';
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/builder/class-astra-builder-loader.php';

// Elementor Compatibility requires PHP 5.4 for namespaces.
if ( version_compare( PHP_VERSION, '5.4', '>=' ) ) {
    require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/compatibility/class-astra-elementor.php';
    require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/compatibility/class-astra-elementor-pro.php';
    require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/compatibility/class-astra-web-stories.php';
}

// Beaver Themer compatibility requires PHP 5.3 for anonymous functions.
if ( version_compare( PHP_VERSION, '5.3', '>=' ) ) {
    require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/compatibility/class-astra-beaver-themer.php';
}

require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/core/markup/class-astra-markup.php';

/**
 * Load deprecated functions
 */
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/core/deprecated/deprecated-filters.php';
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/core/deprecated/deprecated-hooks.php';
require_once ASTRA_THEME_DIR . 'inc/core/deprecated/deprecated-functions.php';


function add_custom_js_inline() {
    ?>
    <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        const observerOptions = {
            root: null,
            rootMargin: '0px',
            threshold: 0.1
        };

        const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
            entries.forEach(entry => {
                if (entry.isIntersecting) {
                    entry.target.classList.add('visible');
                    observer.unobserve(entry.target);
                }
            });
        }, observerOptions);

        document.querySelectorAll('.edplus_anim-L5I9H8second, .edplus_anim-L5I9H8third').forEach(element => {
            observer.observe(element);
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'add_custom_js_inline');



You have an error in one of your plugin, you should try disabling all of them and enabling one by one untill the error comes out again.
Specifically, the error is that the JSON response is dirty, in fact your data should not contain anything but a valid JSON, but your response starts with <script></script>, that means that some plugin is attempting to inject JavaScript the wrong way.
All of your JSON errors are consequences of the same problem.
This may be related to Notice: Function wp_enqueue_script was called incorrectly. but there is not enough information in your question for me to tell you which plugin is doing the wrong thing, so my suggestion is, once again, to disable all plugins and trying to re-enable them one by one.
One thing that I want you to understand is that the error can be placed elsewhere and even if you see something like Notice: WP_Theme_JSON_Resolver::get_user_data(): Error maybe it has nothing to do with your theme, but something is adding invalid output to any JSON response in your site, and that is only one of the places where the error is causing problems.

Hi, thanks a lot for your detailed analysis. I actually have used troubleshooting mode and have disabled all the plugins and also have switched themes. I have validated theme.json file of the active themes via schema. One important things to mention is that I have about three WP sites on the same directory in my server. All of them face similar issues and the main thing hindering me is the "response is not a valid json response" error due to which I cannot update my sites.  As I mentioned that I have used troubleshooting mode by disabling all plugins, could the error be server side?

If you have the same error after disabling all plugins it could be not WP related. Please try uploading a real JSON file in your server, then try loading this file with anything and see if the <script></script> tag is injected in that file too, if so you have something on your server, probably a malware, injecting unwanted content in any response.
